# EF difference between ctx.Object.Select and obj.Select

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Today I ran into something a bit weird.

I used mini-profiler to see the SQL queries executed.

It seems that when using obj.Children.Select(x => x.Prop1).SingleOrDefault() the query executed get ALL columns.
However, using ctx.Children.Select(x => x.Prop1 && x.IDParent == idObj).SingleOrDefault() gets only Prop1.

Any idea why the difference?

Comment: dont you mean to have a `Where` clause in there?

Comment: I had a where in both cases. but I didn't thought it was relevant to include it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the first query gets executed here:

```
obj.Children. ...
```

And the second query gets excuted here:

```
... .SingleOrDefault()
```

You get the first query for the full entity with all columns because the navigation property gets loaded due to **lazy loading**. After the entity is loaded your `Select` will be applied in memory. The database query is already finished at this point when you project to the single property.

The second query performs the projection (selecting a single column) really in the database and does not load more than this column.